# What is the best way to represent an album and song entity in an e-commerce schema?

Tags: erd

I'm designing a simple mp3(music) ecommerce site, customers can either buy a single Track or whole Album, an Album is made up of Tracks, so there is a one to many relationship between an Album and a Track as shown below. I thought it would be a good idea to have one Orders table and one Product table, the idea I had is to have a generic Product table to represent either a Track or an Album as a Product but I'm kinda struggling to design that on my ERD. I was thinking in a inheritance approach.  all Tracks will have the same price but Albums will have an individual prices.

What is the best way to achieve this requirement? in the orders table I need to see if it was a Track or Album purchased and money spent.

I have searched for examples and samples without any luck.

An example will also help a lot.

[image: Snippet of the ERD]

Answer (score 5):

There really is not a **One True Answer**, but there are plenty of samples available on the web.  One site is: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

This is actually a site with many simple data models. I would not call these a complete solution, but it is a good resource for getting started.

For a CD Collection there is a sample model, that focuses on content, not on the commercial side of selling content.

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/cd_collection/index.htm

In addition if you search for something like *example database model music* you will find other examples.

Comment: Thanks, I have been searching for some time looking for an example on the net without any luck but I will look at the above links as well

Comment: And, of course, that same site has sample databases for sales situations.